# Why is any Kloosterman sum real?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum

I've read that the Kloosterman sum $$S(m, n; c) := \sum_{a \pmod c}^* e \left( \frac{m a + n \overline{a}}{c} \right)$$
is real for any $m, n \in \mathbf{Z}$ and $c \geq 1$. After a lot of scribbling I couldn't find a proof for this fact and on the web it is always stated without proof.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Make the change of variables $a \mapsto -a$.

Answer (score 1):

That the Kloosterman sum is real is given as an exercise in the article at the following link: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M259.02/kloos.pdf